# Need reusable generic method which Convert from JSONString to list of objects with Jackson Library

Tags: java, android, jackson

Here is my code

```
 List<Image> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(imageString, CollectionType.construct(List.class, SimpleType.construct(Image.class)));
```

Dont know how to make reusable method which in parameter 1 get Class for list, parameter 2 JSONString which we are converting to the list of objects.

PLEASE dont blame for maybe stupid type of question. Just learning and want to know how to make code better and reusable

Comment: There is nothing wrong in asking. Just to avoid misunderstanding. Could you please provide some kind of example what do you expect to achieve? How you would like to use this method?

Comment: @MichałZiober I have several steps in this process. 1 I am getting JSONString from sharedPrefs -> 2 convert it to list of objects -> 3 with other method going through that list and get needed object. For example as parameter i put Moscow it goes through all objects and give me objects Country with name Russia and capital Russia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question:

```
private <T> List<T> theMethod(String json) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<T>>(){});
}
```

...in your sample it would be:

```
private <T> List<T> theMethod(String json, Class<T> theClass) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, CollectionType.construct(List.class, SimpleType.construct(theClass)));
}
```

Comment: Sure, here is an example: `List<String> listOfStrings = theMethod("theJson", String.class);`

Comment: Cool it works . Thank you! BUT readValue also asking for try/catch. So I added it by myself but you could edit your answer for perfect match

Comment: Oops you're right. However I'll add throws (let external entity handle the thing).